# Converting .csv file into specific file format

Tags: r, excel, file, csv, formatting

I have a .csv file that I need in a specific format, and I can't figure out how to get it into that format.  I have an example file for the format that I need to convert it into, it is a text file but it looks like this:

```
> "Date" "ID" "Name" "Date2" "Website" "Size" "IDdigit" "Value" "2012/03/12" 74093518 "Jason" "2013/12/16" "http://www.website.com" "94,595 Cats" NA
```

etc.  So every term apart from number strings and NA are in double quotes.The .csv file has the same terms but just in the regular excel layout.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't find anything that has been able to help so far.  It needs to be converted into this specific format to be read into R.  Please let me know if I can provide any more information to help.

Comment: you know that `R` is able to read csv files ? why the specific format ?

Comment: Yes - but I get an error message when I try and read it in as a csv, and the only difference between the example file (which works when I read it into R) and this file is the formatting.  Just to note, I get the following error message:

Error in .Call2("solve_user_SEW0", start, end, width, PACKAGE = "IRanges") :
  solving row 400: range cannot be determined from the supplied arguments (too many NAs)

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're using to read in the file?

Comment: then you should probably change the options from your command when you read the csv. What was your R code ?

Comment: data_example <- read.table(EXAMPLEDATA, header=T, stringsAsFactors=T)
data_mine <- read.csv(MYDATA, header=T, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=T)